# Can not run Nodemon in node project build with Typescript (In Windows)

Tags: node.js, typescript, server, build, nodemon

Node project is built with **Typescript** and there are three script in package.json file but when I run it shows ...

If i run this project in **ubuntu** it works fine but not in **windows**

[Image of output terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fR6S.png)

but after this nodemon is not start to run project.

Script in Package.json

```
"start": "tsc --watch & nodemon dist/index.js",
"lint": "tslint -c tslint.json 'src/**/*.ts' --fix",
"build": "tsc"
```

Help me to solve this, Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I have tried && in this line also but not works... 

tsc --watch & nodemon dist/index.js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be missing an `&` character between `tsc --watch` and `nodemon dist/index.js`. A single `&` is not a valid `and` operator:

```
"start": "tsc --watch && nodemon dist/index.js",
```

**Update** It looks like the issue is on Windows. Commonly this issue is solved by using a library such as concurrently or cross-env to execute commands in a similar way on Windows. After you've installed concurrently:

```
"start": "concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"nodemon dist/index.js\"",
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @jimit_jd Okay, update your question to reflect that. Also add to your question what platform you are attempting to execute this command on.

Comment: If i run this project in ubuntu it works fine but not in windows

Comment: @jimit_jd I've updated the question to show one approach using a library for both windows and other platforms.

Comment: Hey Alexander , It works after using concurrently , Thank you so much for your help

Comment: But why it is not running normally in Windows as run in Ubuntu ??

Comment: It's processed differently on windows just like it wouldn't work if you tried to set an environment variable in the command like `ENV=dev` or something it wouldn't work on windows.

Comment: Okay I see , and once again Thank you Alexander :)